# Bellman-Ford optimisation in C

Tags: performance, c, pathfinding

Here is my current code:

```
#define uint uint32_t // unsigned integer
#define sint int32_t  // signed integer

// Declaration of the bellman_ford function 
int bellman_ford(sint links[][3], uint links_size, uint s, int64_t *dist, uint *path, uint nb_nodes);

int bellman_ford(sint links[][3], uint links_size, uint s, int64_t
*dist, uint *path, uint nb_nodes) 
/**  
* Computes the shortest path between a given source node and all other nodes in a weighted graph. 
*  
* Arguments:  
*     links: A 2D array of integers representing the links between nodes. Each row represents a link and contains the indices of the two nodes and the cost of the link.  
*     links_size: The number of links in the links array.  
*     s: The index of the starting node.  
*     dist: An array of size nb_nodes to store the shortest distances from each node to s.  
*     path: An array of size nb_nodes to store the shortest paths from each node to s.  
*     nb_nodes: The total number of nodes in the graph.  
*  
* Returns:  
*    0 if the computation succeeded, 1 if a negative cycle was detected in the graph.  
**/ {
    int updates;

    // Initialize dist and path arrays with memset
    memset(dist, 0x7f, nb_nodes * sizeof(int64_t));
    memset(path, -1, nb_nodes * sizeof(sint));

    dist[s] = 0;

    // Perform nb_nodes - 1 iterations of Bellman-Ford algorithm
    for (uint _ = 0; _ < nb_nodes - 1; _++)
    {
        updates = 0;
        // For each link in the links array, attempt to update shortest distances for each node.
        for (uint j = 0; j < links_size; j++)
        {
            uint node_from = links[j][0];
            uint node_to = links[j][1];
            int64_t cost = links[j][2];

            // If a shorter distance is found, store it in the dist array and update the path array
            if ((dist[node_from] != INT64_MAX) && (dist[node_from] + cost < dist[node_to]))
            {
                dist[node_to] = dist[node_from] + cost;
                path[node_to] = node_from;
                updates++;
            }
        }

        // If no update was made during the previous iteration, exit the loop
        if (updates == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Check for negative cycle in the graph
    for (uint k = 0; k < links_size; k++)
    {
        uint node_from = links[k][0];
        uint node_to = links[k][1];
        int64_t cost = links[k][2];

        // If a shorter distance is still found, there is a negative cycle
        if ((dist[node_from] != INT64_MAX) && (dist[node_from] + cost < dist[node_to]))
        {
            printf("Negative cycle detected\n");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;}
```

I would like to optimize performance as much as possible, with the limitation that the code should remain readable and fluid and the algorithm should not become overly complicated. Also, it is important to keep the same input and output data as now, the code must detect negative cycles and cover corner cases.

I have read interesting stuff which I'd like to implement, (full descriptions are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_faster_algorithm)

> The basic idea of SPFA is the same as the Bellman-Ford algorithm in
> that each vertex is used as a candidate to relax its adjacent
> vertices. The improvement over the latter is that instead of trying
> all vertices blindly, SPFA maintains a queue of candidate vertices and
> adds a vertex to the queue only if that vertex is relaxed. This
> process repeats until no more vertex can be relaxed.

> The performance of the algorithm is strongly determined by the order
> in which candidate vertices are used to relax other vertices. In fact,
> if Q is a priority queue, then the algorithm pretty much resembles
> Dijkstra's. However, since a priority queue is not used here, two
> techniques are sometimes employed to improve the quality of the queue,
> which in turn improves the average-case performance (but not the
> worst-case performance). Both techniques rearrange the order of
> elements in Q so that vertices closer to the source are processed
> first. Therefore, when implementing these techniques, Q is no longer a
> first-in, first-out queue, but rather a normal doubly linked list or
> double-ended queue.

Also, I have read that binary heap and Fibonacci heap might be interesting structures to keep element ordered. Is it a good idea to investigate this direction? (wouldn't it be even better than the trick with the queue they talk about?)

More generally, what would you advise?

EDIT: This post has a continuation here: [Bellman-Ford optimisation in C with Shortest Path Algorithm (SPFA) and Small Label first (SLF)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/284097/bellman-ford-optimisation-in-c-with-shortest-path-algorithm-spfa-and-small-lab)

Comment: When you say _"remain readable"_, do you actually think that `#define`s like `uint` and `sint` and variable names like `_` are good for readability?

Comment: The quoted text talks about priority queues, and in your addendum you talk about heaps.  Are you not aware that heaps are the data structures upon which efficient priority queues are usually implemented?  Some sources even treat "heap" and "priority queue" as synonyms.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I was not, I'm just discovering those terms (I'm new to C even though I coded a bit more in Python and Java) That's actually the main reason why I'm asking here, I don't want to mess with this stuff.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Duly noted, I will post there (I didn't know that branch).

Comment: Do you in fact need to handle graphs having negative weights?  Because if not, then Dijkstra's algorithm is probably a better choice than any variation on Bellman-Ford.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes I do need to handle negative weights (I would have used Dijkstra otherwise, indeed)

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 11):

```
    for (uint _ = 0; _ < nb_nodes - 1; _++)
```

Maybe this was python code translated into C?!?
Repect the norms of the community.
Even though `_` is a *valid* identifier
that we can sneak past the compiler,
that doesn't make it a *good* identifier.

Think about having a conversation with
a colleague over the phone. Are we really
going to talk about this line of code
by reciting "underscore" three times?
The name is essentially saying "nothing
to see here, don't even pronounce me."
Yet after initializing it we need to
be concerned with it twice more.
Please fix this.

And when in doubt, choose `size_t` for an array index.
Then let the compiler take it from there,
in case there's things we'd like to prove
about its maximum magnitude.

---

There's a comment above `memset(dist, 0x7f, ...`,
but it doesn't illuminate the intent of the memset.
At first I thought "positive infinity!" until I noticed
the value is 0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f.
A value like 0xdeadbeef would have been more helpful.

---

Signed link distances apparently are
constrained to fall within some range of values,
smaller than what the C compiler allows for.
The range is not documented in narrative nor comments.
The range is not checked by an `assert` or similar test.
We perform signed comparisons against `dist` elements.
It is hard for caller to know if he is submitting
valid inputs, and it is hard to know if we get
back correct results, for some nebulous
definition of "correct".

---

Here's the int32_t declaration:

```
sint links[][3]
```

Here's the use:

```
            int64_t cost = links[j][2];
```

The upcast is unexpected.
Please declare cost to be a signed 32-bit quantity.
Or describe the typical distribution of path lengths
so we know how many orders of magnitude we're talking about.

More generally, the motivating use case was never introduced, nor example values. It appears it's important to describe how both
distances and costs are range limited in your business use case,
and perhaps introduce appropriate high-level types.
This comes up with e.g. comparing distance against `INT64_MAX`
instead of, say, `MAX_DISTANCE`.
I'm not going to attempt to scroll through any more of this source.

---

This code appears to achieve some of its design goals,
in that it runs without crashing and computes correct
results for some digraphs, even ones with a constrained
set of edges having negative weights.

No example data or unit tests appeared in this submission.

I would not be willing to delegate or accept maintenance
tasks for the codebase in its current form.

Comment: that was indeed a code translated from python :) I have edited my message with a new version of the code and corrected the different points as I understood them. The upcast to int64_t is mandatory (non-negotiable request from higher authorities), as well as the choice of the other cast. But this might change in the future, hence the use of define in the beginning of the code to make a change easier. Also, I'm still working on the remark on the value range

Comment: @c.leblanc Please read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for information specific to Code Review Stack Exchange.

Comment: @SolomonUcko While I'm thankful for theses advices, my initial question about optimizing the performance of the algorithm remains open (with more information about that request in the edit I just made). EDIT: maybe you're talking about this ? "Do not add an improved version of the code after receiving an answer" What should I do then ?

Comment: @c.leblanc Yep, that's what I'm referring to. "If you'd like to share the revised version of your code, the following are acceptable (and by no means mandatory) options:

    Posting a new question. If you incorporate advice from one or more answers, but are still unsure that the code is as good as it should be, then post a new question with your revised code. For the benefit of other users, add mutual links: mention the previous question in the new question, and add a comment on the old question linking to the follow-up question." Meanwhile, I've added an optimization idea to my answer.

Answer (score 6):

A few pieces of advice you can consider:

- As far as I'm aware, documentation comments are conventionally immediately before the declaration, not between the signature and the body of the implementation.
- I think you meant to `memset` `dist` with `0xff`/`-1` (all bits set) rather than `0x7f` (one bit unset).
- It would make more sense to declare `updates` when it's initialized to `0`, rather than at the start of the function, to prevent it from getting used where it shouldn't be used.
- Why do you have `typedef`s for the 32-bit integers, but not the 64-bit integer?
- Why is the signature line-wrapped in the implementation but not the declaration?
- What is this check intended to do? `dist[node_from] != INT64_MAX`
- To give optimizing compilers more power, you can add the [`restrict` keyword](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/restrict) to the pointer/array parameters.

Comment: I edited a new version of the code with fixes. I don't think I need 0xff/-1 ? I just want to set all value to the maximum possible (in theory the Bellman Ford algorithm is using infinity there). Also ```dist[node_from] != INT64_MAX``` was used because its is not necessary to check updates if the cost to the node is still set to maximum value (//infinity), anyway this piece of code doesn't make sense in the new version.

Comment: @c.leblanc `memset` with `0x7f` results in `0x7f7f7f7f`, not `0x7fffffff`.

Comment: I'm really not an expert on that. But it seems to work (I have the correct value if I print the element of the array). Also I couldn't use 0x7fffffff in memset but I could use 0x7f, which is interpreted or smth as the correct number when associated to an int64_t ?

Comment: @c.leblanc You can just manually loop through to initialize the values. I'm not sure why it seems to work; it might break if you end up with values greater than `0x7f7f7f7f7f7f7f7f`.

Comment: I was trying to avoid that solution but if it is risky I will do that. Actually, how come memset can't handle ```0x7fffffff``` ?

Comment: @c.leblanc: For [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5919802/147845), `memset` takes an `int` parameter even though [it sets bytes, not words](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memset).

Comment: @c.leblanc If you need to fill a range of memory with copies of a four-byte quantity, and it isn’t an array of 32-bit elements, you need to cast to `char*` and use a `memcpy()` loop. (You could only cast to `uint32_t*` portably if you know the pointer is correctly-aligned.)

Comment: @Davislor: They have `int64_t *dist` and a length in number of `int64_t` elements.  Almost certainly they should be looping over that array and filling it with `INT64_MAX`.  IDK why you'd want `memcpy` for this, unless you mean using it to do 4-byte aliasing-safe stores.  If you did want 4-byte patterns inside an array of int64_t, you could loop over the int64_t elements storing `0x7fffffff7fffffff`.

Comment: @PeterCordes You would need to use `memcpy()`, as I said, for a range of memory that is *not* an array of properly-aligned elements. I agree, in this case, you can simply loop over the array. I should have said that an array of 64-bit integers works too, though.